# Screen Rotation on 20.04 with Gnome 3.36 not working as expected

Tags: gnome, lenovo, touchscreen, display-rotation

I have the following problem:
Screen rotation works like a charm but there is an annoying problem:

When i try to open a **video in fullscreen mode** the screen orientation switches after about 2 seconds (happens in the browser (i.e. youtube) and also with the gnome video player)

So at first the orientation is correct (normal orientation) and after about 2 seconds it flips +180 degree - means upside down.And then it stays upside down as long as I am in full screen mode. When exiting the full-screen mode the orientiation becomes normal again.

I already tried to lock and unlock screen rotation in the gnome topbar. But the problem still exists.

...Besides I don't want to uninstall the automatic screen rotation sensors because it is working very nicely for all the other situations. Of course only if there is no other way to solve this problem.

Ubuntu 20.04
Gnome 3.36
Lenovo Thinkpad Yoga x380

thanks

Update:

I just tried to disable fractional scaling to the normal setup and the problem was solved by this. So the problem is only when fractional scaling is enabled...

Comment: I just tried to disable fractional scaling to the normal setup and the problem was solved by this. So the problem is only when fractional scaling is enabled....

Comment: It is better to add important info directly to the question. Could you  download and try 20.10 Live CD? May be it is a bug that already fixed.

Comment: Sorry but i couldn't add it... I realized it about 1 day after...so the info was not there the time i wrote the post...Will try 20.10 asap...

Comment: Thx know what you mean...